# Issue when registering 32bit COM from outside the system(SysWOW64) directory

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio, regsvr32

I'm having an issue in accomplishing the registered state of a 32bit component or library (say `OCX` or `dll`), for the purpose of compiling the project directly dependent upon it.

Standard procedure for achieving it is via regsvr32.exe within SysWOW64 folder pointing to the parameter of component/library destination, e.g. `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe someComponent.ocx` .

However, after messing with the registry and reinstalling the component the only way I got it working
was by copying that `.ocx` and its dependency files into `SysWOW64`.

Only then, after using regsvr32(all within the same SysWOW64 folder) Visual Studio compiler managed successfully compiling it, sort of like it was blind to the fact that I've already done that - proven
in turn by the fact of the presence of the key within the Windows registry.

Has anyone experienced something like this and why would it register only via "direct" presence of the component within the SysWOW64 system folder as opposed to the "distant" in some other, non-system folder??

Thanks

Comment: There is no requirement that COM objects be registered in the system directories, but it's hard to guess what `messing with the registry` means or broke. What is the exact error message when it fails to compile?

Comment: Error message by Visual Studio is a TypeInitializationException, HRESULT:0x8007007E, any clues ?

Comment: Make sure to run regsvr32 in administator mode so it registers the DLL or OCX successfully.

Comment: @dasquest `0x8007007E` is [`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d) "*the specified module could not be found*". Most likely there are registry entries missing, or pointing to the wrong path. You could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to check what's being looked up where.

Comment: @dxiv That's the catch-22, there is the key registered as I stated above, yet VS Compiler doesn't get it, even after clearing and rebuilding the project. Since it's reporting that exception in the context of the specific CLSID and there is such an exact entry within the registry, it adds to the confusion.

Comment: Btw, explicitly said, cmd is being run under Administrator privileges.

Comment: @dasquest Not sure what you mean by "***the*** *key*". COM registration uses several keys in different places.

Comment: @dxiv CLSID Key of the 'exceptional' .ocx component.

Comment: @dxiv https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/free1/uploads/mapwindow1/original/1X/b771625f9c7c7ced8db1c8984cb8f3d79b6eda57.png

Comment: @dasquest Again, there is no one single "*key*" responsible (or sufficient) for COM registration. You need several keys for the class, interface, typelib etc and they all need to be in sync. Watch ProcMon and see for yourself.

Comment: @dxiv When I use earlier versions of the project (older OCX but still 32bit) it compiles perfectly. By single key, I meant the one offered by the exception message(check the screenshot), key of the .ocx component as a registry entry.

Comment: @dasquest Older versions may be using different GUIDs, so that's not necessarily relevant to why the version you want doesn't work. It sounds like a missing or wrong registration on your machine, but that's something only you can debug. At the risk of repeating myself one more time, ProcMon can help with that.

Comment: @dxiv Unfortunately it's the same GUID in all of them (catch-22 remember :P ). Used both ProcMon and DependencyWalker plus RegDllView. It is relevant since it tells me if the component needed for the compilation is present as a registry entry.

Comment: @dxiv why would it work previously and not currently except if the new version component is unable to see SysWOW64 dependencies without being present 'first-person' in that folder alongside.

Comment: @dasquest `Used ProcMon` So what file coming from which registry key did ProcMon report as not found or failing to load?

Comment: @dxiv The .OCX component file from the screenshot, however DependecyWalker reported files that could've only be found within that SysWOW64 system folder.

Comment: @dasquest Are you saying ProcMon reports the .ocx was not found in the directory where you copied it? This is hard to follow without seeing the actual PML procmon logfile.

Answer (score 0):

So none of these were right, but I'm going to leave this answer because OP confirmed that none them are right, which narrows the problem.

There are several ways this can go wrong. All of these cases do not work:

- Registering a 32 bit dll in C:\Program Files.
- Registering a 32 bit dll in C:\Windows\System32
- Registering a 32 bit dll while the current directory is in or under one of those.
- Not registering as admin. This does wild things in 32 bit code that can lead to confusing problems.

Comment: Not a single one of these were missed, no worries. Thanks for the attempt anyways.